# resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode: crashing on iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I'm using this code to stretch an image correctly, however on iOS 5.1 it crashes.
If I remove the resizingMode from the end, it works but the image is then tiled and looks funny.
Any ideas why it's crashing?

Thanks

```
self.scrollViewImage.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SysInfoBackBox"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 40, 40, 40) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a new method introduced in iOS 6.0 and not supported on previous versions. If you want to make the code run on previous versions, you will have to check at runtime if UIImage instance responds to selector for that method and implement alternative if it doesn't.

```
if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:)]) {
    self.scrollViewImage.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SysInfoBackBox"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 40, 40, 40) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
} else {
    // alternative
}
```

Comment: Ahh so it is. Thanks. I didn't realise it should just crash. I'd have expected a compiler warning as my build version is iOS 5

Comment: Build version? You mean deployment target or SDK version? Deployment target only sets the lowest version you want your app to try to run on, ensuring backwards-compatibility is up to you. If you set SDK version to iOS 5.1 or older it will give you error, not a warning.

Comment: Yes deployment target sorry. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: btw is there any alternative of this method for iOS 5 ?

Answer (score 4):

This function
    `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:`
don't work on ios 5.0 (only >=6.0), but 
    `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`
does, try to use it. Maybe a simple replacement can help you.

Answer (score -2):

I replayed to another question that should be related to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623534/2028575

but if you like I can put here the sare answer:

this was happening only with devices with iOS5.x resizing an UIImageView that diplay an UIImage created in this way:

```
    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topCapHeight, leftCapWidth, topCapHeight, leftCapWidth);
    image = [originalImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
```

this is probably an iOS bug that has been fixed in iOS6.x

if your case is resizing the image with a mirror criteria you can use this way:

create a category of UIImage and add this instance method:

```
- (UIImage*)resizableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight </b>
{
    UIImage *image = nil;    
    float osVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (osVersion < 6.0) {
        image = [self stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCapWidth topCapHeight:topCapHeight];
    } else {
        UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topCapHeight, leftCapWidth, topCapHeight, leftCapWidth);
        image = [self resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
    }
    return image;
}
```

the method : 
 `- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight`

has been deprecated in the iOS documentation but not in the framework, this mean that you can use it when you are running your app in a device whit iOS5.x without any problem, and user the new supported method with devices with iOS 6 or higher.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: if you make it in this way this post should be closed as duplicated of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528388/crashing-using-resizableimagewithcapinsetsuiedgeinsetsmake