# Crashing using resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

Basically, I am using resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake. But I am not sure if this is the source of my crash. I am adding these resizable images on my table cell. I am not exactly sure on how this is occuring.

Here's the log.

```
 Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xa1eab0c4
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3966c5d0 objc_msgSend + 16
    1   Foundation                      0x3aa1750c probeGC + 60
    2   Foundation                      0x3aa1d526 -[NSConcreteMapTable removeObjectForKey:] + 30
    3   UIKit                           0x39e9f46c -[_UIImageViewPretiledImageWrapper dealloc] + 76
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3966e490 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 164
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x3a72882c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
    6   Foundation                      0x3aa12e10 -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 116
    7   UIKit                           0x39b0f80c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 220
    8   UIKit                           0x39acb892 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 254
    9   QuartzCore                      0x37fce4e6 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
    10  QuartzCore                      0x37fce088 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
    11  QuartzCore                      0x37fcefac CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
    12  QuartzCore                      0x37fce996 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 234
    13  QuartzCore                      0x37fce7a8 CA::Transaction::commit() + 312
    14  QuartzCore                      0x37fce60c CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
    15  CoreFoundation                  0x3a7ba93e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x3a7b8c34 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x3a7b8f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 742
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x3a72c238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x3a72c0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
    20  GraphicsServices                0x37a65336 GSEventRunModal + 70
    21  UIKit                           0x39b1c28c UIApplicationMain + 1116
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, this was happening only with devices with iOS5.x resizing an UIImageView that diplay an UIImage created in this way:

```
    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topCapHeight, leftCapWidth, topCapHeight, leftCapWidth);
    image = [originalImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
```

this is probably an iOS bug that has been fixed in iOS6.x

if your case is resizing the image with a mirror criteria you can use this way:

create a category of UIImage and add this instance method:

```
- (UIImage*)resizableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight </b>
{
    UIImage *image = nil;    
    float osVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (osVersion < 6.0) {
        image = [self stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCapWidth topCapHeight:topCapHeight];
    } else {
        UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topCapHeight, leftCapWidth, topCapHeight, leftCapWidth);
        image = [self resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
    }
    return image;
}
```

the method : 
 `- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight`

has been deprecated in the iOS documentation but not in the framework, this mean that you can use it when you are running your app in a device whit iOS5.x without any problem, and user the new supported method with devices with iOS 6 or higher.

Comment: Alleluia brother. I had another problem when using `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` because I can't use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` and apparently iOS 5 uses `UIImageResizingModeTile` instead of the necessary (in my case) `UIImageResizingModeStretch`. It works when using `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth`. For the sake of being compatible with the future versions (iOS 7 upwards) it might be useful to use your category but as of now (iOS 6) it works using `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` directly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI.

I also had a crash similar to this and the fix was actually not in the code, but in the asset itself.

As Apple Documentation states the resizable area of the asset needs to be 1px by 1px, so **ensure** that it is.

> *- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets*
>
> During scaling or resizing of the image, areas covered by a cap are not scaled or resized. Instead, the pixel area not covered by the cap in each direction is tiled, left-to-right and top-to-bottom, to resize the image. This technique is often used to create variable-width buttons, which retain the same rounded corners but whose center region grows or shrinks as needed. For best performance, use a tiled area that is a 1x1 pixel area in size.