# UIImage not stretching on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have a UIImage that is 1024 x 1 pixels. This image has to stretch to fill a UIImageView that is 1024 x 50 pixels.

This image is loaded initially on a NSArray and then I do this:

```
 UIImage *image = nil;

    if ([UIImage respondsToSelector:@selector(resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:)]) { // ios >= 6.0
        image = [[myImages objectAtIndex:0] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero
resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    } else {
        image = [[myImages objectAtIndex:0] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0f topCapHeight:0.0f];
    }
```

this works great on iOS 6 but not on iOS 5. Why?

I mean, the image stretches beautifully and fills the UIImageView on iOS 6 but not on 5.

The UIImageView is set with these parameters:

```
UIImageView myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,50)];
[myImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill | UIViewContentModeRedraw];
[myImageView setImage:image];
```

Comment: `resizableImageWithCapInsets:...` is an *instance* method, so you cannot use `respondsToSelector:` on the class itself, you'd need an instance for that (otherwise you're checking if the `UIImage` *class* responds to the selector). You could simply replace it with `instancesRespondToSelector:` here.

Comment: ah, ok, but it was working fine, for some reason.

Comment: Btw, it doesn't really make sense to create a stretchable image with zero edge insets / cap widths. You could just use the original image there (the default is basically to stretch the entire image, these methods are only meant to be used when you want the borders of your image *not* to stretch). I suspect that the behavior for this "edge case" changed from iOS 5 to 6.

Comment: Ok I agree but that was the only way I managed to make the image stretch on iOS 6 but iOS 5 is not liking it.

Comment: adding the image to the UIImageView without using this stretchable stuff makes no difference. The image continues to not stretch. Man, this is a nightmare.

Comment: Your `contentMode` is also wrong. You're not supposed to combine multiple content modes, it's not a bit mask (as opposed to `UIViewAutoresizingMode` for example). Using the binary OR (`|`) operator with those two content modes results in `3`, which is equivalent to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`. Set it to just `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` (which is the default anyway, so you can also remove that line entirely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` with a good edge insets value instead of your `UIEdgeInsetsZero`. To do so, work out the width and height of your view. Then:

```
image = [myView resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(
             height/2.0-1, width/2.0-1, height/2.0-1, width/2.0-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[myImages objectAtIndex:0] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0f topCapHeight:0.0f]]
```

This is deprecated method in iOS 5. please go through this

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

It may help you.

Comment: you have not read my code. Despite apple saying that resizableImageWithCapsInside is a iOS 5 API, when this code of mine runs on iOS 5, the line respondToSelector returns returns NO, that is resizableImageWithCapsInside does not work for iOS 5. If I force it to run the app crashes.

Comment: by the way, just using resizableImageWithCapInsets: does not solve the problem.

Comment: @RubberDuck go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414844/resizableimagewithcapinsetsresizingmode-crashing-on-ios-5-1

resizableImageWithCapsInside method is introduced in iOS 6

Comment: Well when your app crashes what error you are getting in console.

Comment: ok, I was using resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode: on iOS 5, now I have corrected that to just resizableImageWithCapInsets: and the crash is gone but the image do not stretches. Using resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode: on iOS6 makes the image stretch.

Comment: Set the content mode sizetofit.

Comment: there is no content mode of kind sizeToFit. There is an API called sizeToFit that is a UIIMageView but this does not make sense, because the UIImageView is being created by frame, with the size I want and if I do sizeToFit it will shrink to the size of the image that is 1 pixel high. I have added more informations to the question.

Comment: can you share your screen shot. with ios 5 and ios 6